# Updating content after major upgrade from 5 to 6 (changes to production site need to be reflected in dev environment)

Tags: 6, ubercart, upgrading

I have been tasked with a major upgrade from D5 to D6.  The upgrade is now complete and fully themed on my development server.  The current production site is very busy, with dozens of nodes being added on a daily basis.  I need to somehow sync the content from the D5 site to the D6 site, and am wondering if there is any modules to assist or recommended way of doing this?  I just need to retrieve the content and Ubercart orders from the last month and port them to the D6 site.  Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I don't think there's an easy one-click way to do it. Check out [http://drupal.org/node/859434](http://drupal.org/node/859434)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not found a better alternative to [migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module till date and I have done lots of migration including ubercart order migration. It has served me well for:

- ASP.Net (MSSQL server) -> Drupal migration
- D6 -> D7 Migration
- Rails (MySQL) -> Drupal Migration

There are tons of other modules like node_export, views bonus pack, uuid features, deploy that will let you export content out of drupal site but nothing scales better than migrate module. Having said that, its some effort as you need to write your migration classes, but it comes with excellent features like:

- Incremental Migration ( you can test your migration class, with small subset of content)
- Rollback ( In case you realize you missed something )
- Solid drush interface.

Also, once you get a hang of it you keep appreciating the fact that it always work. It knows what has been imported, it reports on warnings during migration, gives you a status update on your migration. Can't recommend it enough!! and the best part is minimum downtime, you keep syncing content till the last moment.

Comment: Unfortunately I have found that the migrate module isn't well suited for some of the migrations I have done and I ended up writing my own migration scripts that were almost as complicated. I have tried using it on another migration and it worked for simple things like initial imports. But doing things like added multiple file entries or doing a lot of file detecting and data manipulation it seems to fall short. Though maybe I just need to learn more about using the migrate module. That said I did end up contributing some patches to it that are now in core.

Comment: What kind of migrations do you think it can't handle?

Comment: Multi-stage multi-file migrations. It struggles with. It got me most of the way with a two part file to node migration. When I had to attach a second file to the migrated nodes automatically it started the process and then kept dying on me. I ended up writing a free standing script to finish the job.

Comment: As you say, Migrate takes some effort to use - can you recommend any tutorials or examples of employing it for typical use cases, like the one I describe in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48048/merge-content-e-g-a-forum-with-nodes-terms-and-users-from-one-drupal-site-i ?