# Merge content (e.g. a forum, with nodes, terms and users) from one Drupal site into another

Tags: 7, migrations, importing-exporting

How would I merge content (e.g. a forum, with nodes, terms and users) from one Drupal site into another?

Here's my specific use case:

- I have a local site which just contains nodes, terms and users for a forum (these were imported with http://drupal.org/project/phpbb2drupal - and before you suggest just using it on my live site, I can't get it to work there, running into the issues described at http://drupal.org/node/1033316 )
- I have a live site which has no forum, but has its own nodes, terms and users.
- I'd like to merge the local site forum into the live site, adding the forum to the live site.

Comment: Drupal community have had a hard time searching for the solution for this problem, but I'm afraid there's no ideal solution for this. I too required [this a while back](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34056/how-to-add-data-from-one-drupal-site-to-other) but there is no one satisfactory solution for this. I ended using Deploy module but it is not reliable.

Comment: +1 for the link to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34056/how-to-add-data-from-one-drupal-site-to-other

Answer (score 2):

If it was just for nodes i would say use this:

http://drupal.org/project/node_export

As you need to migrate users and taxonomy terms as well I would use this:

http://drupal.org/project/migrate

Although there will be some php OOP coding to do.

Comment: Thanks. Surely this is such a common use case that's someone's written some php code I could nab?

Comment: Content migration between Drupals system is one of its biggest weaknesses at the moment, and one of the things that is being worked on for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to dump into your new drupal 7:http://goo.gl/GPmG9F